Battery recommendation for custom quadcopter build with 1.5kg payload capacity
I'm building a custom quadcopter and need advice on selecting an appropriate battery. My drone needs to lift a payload of approximately 1.5kg.
Here are the main components of my build:

Frame: E-433-Q450 Quadcopter Frame - PCB Version
Motors: 4x E-88-A A2212-1800KV BLDC Brushless Motors
ESCs: 4x E-372 30A BLDC Electronic Speed Controllers
Propellers: E-90 10x4.5 inch - 1045/1045R CW CCW Propeller Pairs
Flight Controller: E-68 ARDUINO UNO R3 DIP IC-Clone Model

Sensors:

E-14 MPU6050-Triple Axis Gyro Accelerometer Module
E-147-NEO-6M GPS Module with EPROM

Additional components include an NRF24L01 module, joystick, and various connectors and wires.
Given these specifications and the 1.5kg payload requirement:

What type and capacity of LiPo battery would you recommend?
What voltage should I look for?
Are there any specific brands or models you'd suggest?
How might this battery choice affect my estimated flight time?

